# cartesian product of function handles

Tags: matlab, function

I want to be able to build the Cartesian product of functions. For example, consider following two sets of functions

```
a = function_handle1;
b = function_handle2;
c = function_handle3;
d = function_handle4;

result = cartprod({a b}, {c d});
```

`result` should be something like this:

```
result = [a c; a d; b c; b d];
```

Is there something in MATLAB which allows me to do this?

Comment: Does it have to be a matrix? What about cell, `result = {a c; a d; b c; b d}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go-to function for the Cartesian product in MATLAB is [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) (or [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html)).  In this case, the trick is to pack the handles into a cell array and use the indexes from `meshgrid` perform the operation. For example,

```
>> a=@sum; b=@mean; c=@std; d=@var;
>> handles = {a,b,c,d}
handles = 
    @sum    @mean    @std    @var
```

Now that the handles are stored in a cell array, you can build the output array via indexing:

```
>> [II,JJ]=meshgrid(1:2,3:4);
>> result=handles([II(:) JJ(:)])
result = 
    @sum     @std   
    @sum     @var
    @mean    @std   
    @mean    @var
```

Keep in mind you need to use curly braces (`{}`) to access the contents of a cell:

```
>> x = [1 2];
>> result{1,1}(x)
ans =
     3
>> result{1,2}(x)
ans =
    0.7071
>> result{2,2}(x)
ans =
    0.5000
```

Or you can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
>> x = [1 2];
>> cellfun(@(c)c(x),result(1,:))
ans =
    3.0000    0.7071
```

Note that you cannot have regular arrays of function handles. If you try any form of concatenation (e.g. `horzcat`, `vertcat`, `cat`), you get the error `Nonscalar arrays of function handles are not allowed; use cell arrays instead.`.  It is also possible to assign the handles to fields of a `struct` array and use `structfun` as demonstrated in [`function_handle` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html).